# RTL paragraph in LTR footnote results in odd margins

Tags: footnotes, polyglossia, arabic, bidi

In an English text, I have some Arabic passages. Now I have the special case that there is an Arabic paragraph in a (English) footnote. I have tried two variants, but neither produce satisfying results:

When marking the text using `\textarabic{}`, the second line of the paragraph is left aligned, which is unnatural for Arabic text.

When using `\begin{Arabic}\end{Arabic}`, the text direction is changed to RTL, which makes the text flow correctly, but the margins are now odd: The text reaches into the left margin which is reserved to the footnote, while there is an additional margin on the right.

[image: Example with both variants]

A minimal example is below.

Is there a variant that sets the Arabic paragraph correctly as RTL (i.e., starting the second line on the right), while respecting the overall margins of the footnote?

```latex
\documentclass[english, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\setmainfont[]{Charis SIL}
\setsansfont[]{Charis SIL Compact}
%% languages/scripts
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[]{english}
\setotherlanguage[]{arabic}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}
%% No additional space between sentences
\frenchspacing

Christians are
compared to \emph{goim} and are also accused of heresy (\emph{herejía}),
mainly because of their inability to understand revelation. They are
compared to donkeys (\emph{ḥimār}): an ``asno ke lieba libros''
(``donkey that carries books'').\footnote{Cardaillac (1972, 2:41),
  Madrid, National Library of Spain, Aljamiado 4944, f.~45f. Algiers,
  National Library of Algeria, Ar. 1557, p.~57, lines 7--8.

  \textarabic{فسجن الله ما اعمى ابصارهم بيدهم الانجيل يقرونه ولا يفهموه انما مثلهم
  كمثل الحمار يحمل اسفارا اصدق الله العظيم ورسول الكريم}

  The expression ``ka-mathal al-ḥimār yaḥmilu asfāran'' is well known by
  Muslims, as it is found in Qur. 62:5 and used by Arabic grammarians as
  an illustrative case study.} but the basic idea is the same in the Arabic
original and the Aljamiado adaptation.

Christians are
compared to \emph{goim} and are also accused of heresy (\emph{herejía}),
mainly because of their inability to understand revelation. They are
compared to donkeys (\emph{ḥimār}): an ``asno ke lieba libros''
(``donkey that carries books'').\footnote{Cardaillac (1972, 2:41),
  Madrid, National Library of Spain, Aljamiado 4944, f.~45f. Algiers,
  National Library of Algeria, Ar. 1557, p.~57, lines 7--8.

  \begin{Arabic}

  فسجن الله ما اعمى ابصارهم بيدهم الانجيل يقرونه ولا يفهموه انما مثلهم
  كمثل الحمار يحمل اسفارا اصدق الله العظيم ورسول الكريم

  \end{Arabic}

  The expression ``ka-mathal al-ḥimār yaḥmilu asfāran'' is well known by
  Muslims, as it is found in Qur. 62:5 and used by Arabic grammarians as
  an illustrative case study.} but the basic idea is the same in the Arabic
original and the Aljamiado adaptation.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `extrafootnotefeatures` option of the `bidi` package. One possibly undesirable side effect is that this makes the footnote rule full width. Presumably this could be redefined.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\PassOptionsToPackage{extrafootnotefeatures}{bidi}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Christians are compared to \emph{goim} and are also accused of heresy
(\emph{herejía}), mainly because of their inability to understand revelation.
They are compared to donkeys (\emph{ḥimār}): an ``asno ke lieba libros''
(``donkey that carries books'').\footnote{Cardaillac (1972, 2:41), Madrid,
  National Library of Spain, Aljamiado 4944, f.~45f. Algiers, National Library
  of Algeria, Ar. 1557, p.~57, lines 7--8.

  \textarabic{فسجن الله ما اعمى ابصارهم بيدهم الانجيل يقرونه ولا يفهموه انما
  مثلهم كمثل الحمار يحمل اسفارا اصدق الله العظيم ورسول الكريم}

  The expression ``ka-mathal al-ḥimār yaḥmilu asfāran'' is well known by
  Muslims, as it is found in Qur. 62:5 and used by Arabic grammarians as an
illustrative case study.} but the basic idea is the same in the Arabic
original and the Aljamiado adaptation.

Christians are compared to \emph{goim} and are also accused of heresy
(\emph{herejía}), mainly because of their inability to understand revelation.
They are compared to donkeys (\emph{ḥimār}): an ``asno ke lieba libros''
(``donkey that carries books'').\footnote{Cardaillac (1972, 2:41), Madrid,
  National Library of Spain, Aljamiado 4944, f.~45f. Algiers, National Library
  of Algeria, Ar. 1557, p.~57, lines 7--8.

  \begin{Arabic}
  فسجن الله ما اعمى ابصارهم بيدهم الانجيل يقرونه ولا يفهموه انما مثلهم كمثل
  الحمار يحمل اسفارا اصدق الله العظيم ورسول الكريم
  \end{Arabic}

  The expression ``ka-mathal al-ḥimār yaḥmilu asfāran'' is well known by
  Muslims, as it is found in Qur. 62:5 and used by Arabic grammarians as an
illustrative case study.} but the basic idea is the same in the Arabic
original and the Aljamiado adaptation.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is helpful in general. I also found out that I can force the classical footnote rule using `\makeatletter \def\footnoterule{\left@footnoterule} \makeatother`

However, we customize the footnote appearance using the KOMAScript system, i.e.:
`\deffootnote{\leftmargin}{1em}{\makebox[\leftmargin][l]{\thefootnotemark}}`

The bidi package generally supports this, but it breaks with the `extrafootnotefeatures` option. If activated, our footnote definition is ignored. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Frederik, this is probably worth a new question with a new MWE.

Comment: Thanks, you’re perfectly right. I posted a [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565250/option-extrafootnotefeatures-in-bidi-package-breaks-komascript-deffootnote).