# Option extrafootnotefeatures in bidi package breaks KOMAScript \deffootnote

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, arabic, bidi

I am using the KOMAScript class `scrartcl` to typeset an academic article containing both English and Arabic. For footnote formatting, I am using `\deffootnote`.

With footnotes that contain Arabic text, the margins are odd. This is fixed by the option `extrafootnotefeatures` of the `bidi` package (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565071/rtl-paragraph-in-ltr-footnote-results-in-odd-margins/565096)). However, this breaks the changes that were made using `\deffootnote`.

[image: Without extrafootnotefeatures (left), with extrafootnotefeatures (right)]

Without `extrafootnotefeatures` (left), with `extrafootnotefeatures` (right)

Is there a way to get proper bidi footnotes while retaining the possibility to change footnote formatting?

A minimal working example is below.

```latex
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\setmainfont[]{Charis SIL}
\setsansfont[]{Charis SIL Compact}
%% languages/scripts
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\PassOptionsToPackage{extrafootnotefeatures}{bidi}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

%% Footnotes (load after polyglossia!)
\deffootnote{\leftmargin}{1em}{%
\makebox[\leftmargin][l]{\thefootnotemark}%
}

% Restore original footnote rule
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\left@footnoterule}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%% No additional space between sentences
\frenchspacing

Christians are
compared to \emph{goim} and are also accused of heresy (\emph{herejía}),
mainly because of their inability to understand revelation. They are
compared to donkeys (\emph{ḥimār}): an ``asno ke lieba libros''
(``donkey that carries books'').\footnote{Cardaillac (1972, 2:41),
  Madrid, National Library of Spain, Aljamiado 4944, f.~45f. Algiers,
  National Library of Algeria, Ar. 1557, p.~57, lines 7--8.

  \begin{Arabic}

  فسجن الله ما اعمى ابصارهم بيدهم الانجيل يقرونه ولا يفهموه انما مثلهم
  كمثل الحمار يحمل اسفارا اصدق الله العظيم ورسول الكريم

  \end{Arabic}

  The expression ``ka-mathal al-ḥimār yaḥmilu asfāran'' is well known by
  Muslims, as it is found in Qur. 62:5 and used by Arabic grammarians as
  an illustrative case study.} but the basic idea is the same in the Arabic
original and the Aljamiado adaptation.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I misled you in the [last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565096/87678)!

The bad rendering is caused by the blank lines around your Arabic text. If you remove this, then it works OK without `bidi`'s `extrafootnotefeatures` option. And then you can use `\deffootnote` without side effects, as well as remove the hack to keep a normal footnote rule:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\deffootnote{\leftmargin}{1em}{\makebox[\leftmargin][l]{\thefootnotemark}}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Christians are compared to \emph{goim} and are also accused of heresy
(\emph{herejía}), mainly because of their inability to understand revelation.
They are compared to donkeys (\emph{ḥimār}): an ``asno ke lieba libros''
(``donkey that carries books'').\footnote{Cardaillac (1972, 2:41), Madrid,
  National Library of Spain, Aljamiado 4944, f.~45f. Algiers, National Library
  of Algeria, Ar. 1557, p.~57, lines 7--8.

  \begin{Arabic}
    فسجن الله ما اعمى ابصارهم بيدهم الانجيل يقرونه ولا يفهموه انما مثلهم كمثل
    الحمار يحمل اسفارا اصدق الله العظيم ورسول الكريم
  \end{Arabic}

  The expression ``ka-mathal al-ḥimār yaḥmilu asfāran'' is well known by
  Muslims, as it is found in Qur. 62:5 and used by Arabic grammarians as an
illustrative case study.} but the basic idea is the same in the Arabic
original and the Aljamiado adaptation.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! I still have no real idea what’s going on. If I set three paragraphs in Arabic, the middle one still will have the weird margins. But this might be an even rarer case, so I guess I can live with this solution for now.

Comment: @Frederik, Oh you're right! That is weird. One stupid workaround is to leave the blank lines around the Arabic and then add in `\leftskip 1cm\rightskip -1cm` before the first Arabic paragraph.